# Monogame problem with flat shading low poly terrain

Tags: xna, monogame, lighting, shading, low-poly

I have been dabbling in 3d rendering recently and I am having a problem with the shading on the mesh I am using.

The code I am using to calculate the normals for all the triangles is as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Indices.Length; i += 3)
{
    Vector3 p1 = Vertices[Indices[i]].Position;
    Vector3 p2 = Vertices[Indices[i + 1]].Position;
    Vector3 p3 = Vertices[Indices[i + 2]].Position;

    Vector3 v1 = p2 - p1;
    Vector3 v2 = p3 - p1;
    Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(v1, v2);

    normal.Normalize();

    Vertices[Indices[i]].Normal = normal;
    Vertices[Indices[i + 1]].Normal = normal;
    Vertices[Indices[i + 2]].Normal = normal;
}
```

None of the triangles in the mesh share vertices so that I can achieve a low polygon look. When it render's half the faces are dark and the other half look like they are correctly shaded. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here and what I may be doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: It looks like half you triangles are probably back facing.  You could turn off back face culling as a quick test, but should re-order the indices if that is that case, so that all your triangles have the correct winding.

Comment: @RichardByron Backfacing as in instead of the indices going counter-clockwise they are going clockwise?

EDIT: Just checked, I had CullMode set to none already so that didn't help, have yet to fix the indices if that is the problem.

Comment: @RichardByron Swapping from clockwise to counter-clockwise fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of my vertices were ordered clockwise instead of counter-clockwise and so they were being drawn upside down. I swapped all the vertices to be ordered in counter-clockwise and that fixed the issue.